# R Nested Lists with complicated Key Value relationship

Tags: r, nested-loops, nested-lists

I can seem to read the JSON structure just fine. Even if I am not doing so properly. But recreating it in R is another story. I've tried so many different ways to try to create the structure I need to turn back into JSON for a student project I am working on showing a heat map of all the US Counties.

Incoming JSON:

```
{
    "VT": {
        "Chittenden": {
            "1899": 47.52,
            "1897": 46.54,
            "2013": 47.07,
            "2014": 46.42,
        },
        "Addison": {
            "2013": 44.28,
            "2014": 40.26,
            "2015": 40.86,
            "2012": 46.96,
            "1988": 40.37,
        },
    },
    "VA": {
        "Floyd": {
            "1944": 53.35,
            "1945": 54.91,
            "1967": 51.58,
            "1950": 51.69,
        },
        "Page": {
            "2013": 53.15,
            "2014": 52.29,
            "2015": 54.52,
        }
    },
}
```

Outgoing JSON:

```
{
    "VT": {
        "Chittenden":{
            "current_avg": 46.50,
            "old_avg": 46.2        
        },
        "Addison":{
            "current_avg": 46.50,
            "old_avg": 46.2        
        },              
    },
    "VA": {
        "Floyd":{
            "current_avg": 46.50,
            "old_avg": 46.2        
        },
        "Page":{
            "current_avg": 46.50,
            "old_avg": 46.2        
        },
    },
}
```

Basically, I need to process the top and turn it into the bottom. I've been trying to use nested for loops and can print what I want to the console. However, when I try to create a new nested list I either get errors or the key names end up being the variables I am using and not the value of the variable.

The following code is just my current iteration. I have tried so many different ways and spent the better part of a day on what would have taken me like 30 min in a language I am more used to like PHP or Python. The lines I try to recreate the structure are at the bottom of the code below.

```
#Create list to put everything into.
avg_list <- list()
state_counter <- 0
#Iterate over the results coming in from JSON
for(state in results){
  current_state <- names(results)[state_counter]
  state_counter <- state_counter + 1
  print(current_state)
  county_counter <- 0

  for(county in state){
    current_county <- names(state)[county_counter]
    county_counter <- county_counter + 1
    #Not sure why I was getting character(0) here but this fixed.
    if(!identical(character(0),current_county)){
      print(current_county)
    }

    year_counter <- 0
    current_sum <- 0
    num_counties_in_current_range <- 0

    for(year in county){
      current_year <- names(county)[year_counter]
      year_counter <- year_counter + 1
      if(!identical(character(0),current_year)){
        print(current_year)
        print(year)
        if(strtoi(current_year) >= current_start_year & strtoi(current_year) <= current_end_year){
          current_sum <- as.double(current_sum) + as.double(year)
          current_counter <- current_counter + 1
          print(current_sum)
          num_counties_in_current_range <- num_counties_in_current_range + 1
        }

      }

    } # End of for year in county

    #Some of the many ways I've tried to recreate something close to the structure I need. 
    #avg_list[[current_state]][[current_county]][["current"]] <- current_sum/num_counties_in_current_range
    #avg_list[current_state][current_county] <- list("current" = current_sum/num_counties_in_current_range)
    #avg_list<- list(current_state = list(current_county = list("current" = current_sum/num_counties_in_current_range)))
    #avg_list <- append(avg_list, list(current_state = list(current_county = list("current" = current_sum/num_counties_in_current_range))))
```

Comment: Any reason for not using the jsonlite package? The most common data structure in R is a data.frame. And you should use this data structure for the grouped aggregation. The jsonlite package makes converting between JSON and a data.frame easy.

Comment: I've tried to use it and flatten it. I've also tried to convert it to a data frame using as.data.frame() but that structure didn't really seem like it was going to be what I needed. I'll look at jsonlite and dataframes again. Thanks